# SVG icons not loading in mapbox

Tags: mapbox, svg, display, loading, mapbox-studio

I uploaded a zipped shapefile to Mapbox with about 500 location data points and tried to display each of those data points with one of 60 different SVG icons. Those SVG icons have been loading inconsistently on both the editor and published view.

Could this be a problem with the SVGs, the data or both?

I assigned the icons to the data points by adding a layer to the map and using the same tileset with a different filter each time. The tileset wasn't over Mapbox's capacity (it's 66KB) but maybe using it in each separate layer slows all the map loading?

Comment: I had all kinds of problems making svg icons in Illustrator that Mapbox liked so I ended up converting them with https://cloudconvert.com/ai-to-svg and then they came in perfectly. Maybe do some tests with that service to see if they work better.

Answer (score 1):

This could be one of two things:

1. A sprite can only be 1024x1024 pixels total, so it's possible not all of the icons are being loaded every time.
2. Something may have gone wrong in the SVG creation process -- see [this help guide](https://www.mapbox.com/help/studio-troubleshooting-svg/) for more info and troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks, I think the sprite was too large. How can I check the sprite size so that I don't accidentally go over 1024x1024 again?